# How to open a file contains CJK characters in perl

Tags: perl, cjk

How can I open the file contains `CJK` characters using perl script:

```
use utf8;
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
```

The above code I am using to open the file and I couldn't find the `CJK` characters and its empty. Input file contains text:

```
\para[para]Details of the electronic structure of the metal the loss to
electron-hole-pair excitations \characters{刘安雯} only 
depends weakly on the metal. The metals exhibit large variation in the 
work function, yet the translational in elasticity is similar in all 
cases. This suggests electron transfer forming a transient 
H\textsuperscript{{\textminus}} is not important. The simulation allows 
us to construct \characters{胡水明} a universal sticking 
function for H and D on metals, which depends only on the H atom 
incidence translational energy and incidence angle as well as the mass of 
the solid's atoms.\endp
```

I am finding this way:

```
while($str=m/(\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs})/xg)
{
     print "Char: --> $&\n";
}
```

Could someone guide where I am doing wrong in my code: Thanks.

**Updated:**

> I don't know but this program works fine and printing the `CJK` characters

```
use utf8;

my $str = "\characters{刘安雯胡水明}";

while($str=~m/(\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs}){1,}/xg) {  print ":: $&\n";  }
```

Comment: `/{1,}/` is usually written as `/+/`. The only change you have made is to ask for "one or more" CJK characters instead of one at a time. Both code samples work fine for me against the text block that you have provided, and I wouldn't expect any different. Or are you saying that matching against the shorter string makes the difference?

Comment: Yes exactly you are right. That shorter string matches however against the full string/file not works at my end.

Comment: Might be the file open/read/write having issues not sure...?

Comment: I would change your header lines to `use utf8` `use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) /`. The latter line will also modify `STDOUT`. But I would be very surprised if that helped with your problem. Since the issue cannot be reproduced, we need to see the code that reads the file. Do you perhaps have another `binmode` on the file handle? It would also help if you showed the output of `print join(' ', map { sprintf '%04X', ord } split //, $str), "\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use utf8;
```

This line tells Perl that the source code contains UTF-8, so it's not related to reading from a file.

```
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
```

This is equivalent to

```
use open IO => 'encoding(utf8)';
```

which sets the encoding for input and output *streams*, i.e. it doesn't change the encoding of standard input and output. To do so, you need to add `:std`:

```
use open IO => ':utf8', ':std';
```

The last line shown,

```
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
```

sets the encoding for STDOUT, which would be already covered by the previous line if it used `:std`.

You didn't show how you opened the file. If you used `<>` or [readline](http://p3rl.org/readline) without specifying a filehandle, you need to set the encoding for the standard input as shown above. If you used a filehandle, I'm out of ideas - it works for me.